# Java: operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm developing a game with LibGDX, and I've tested it successfully on a handful of computers and various operating systems. I sent it to my friend to test, and he got this cryptic error when the game tries to save.

The series of events is as follows:

-The game opens the existing save file using Gdx.files.local(path).readString()

-LibGDX's readString closes the file when it's done. I've verified by checking the source. The file is never opened again.

-Some time later, the game attempts to write over the file, and gets the following error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: save.dat (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at engine.Data.writeFile(Data.java:60)
```

writeFile is defined as follows. Line 60 is the "new FileWriter" line. (Logging omitted for clarity)

```
public static boolean writeFile(String filename, String data) {
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        try {
            fw.write(data);
            success = true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            success = false;
        } finally {
            fw.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

I'm not sure why it only happens on this particular computer- I've tested it on other Windows 7 computers and they don't exhibit the same issue. My friend also tested it on his other Windows 7 computer with no problems.

Is this something I should be worried about, or should I chalk it up to one flaky computer?
Or am I blatantly doing something wrong?

Comment: Either you didn'T close the file properly, or you opened it too soon after closing it. It might also be that something else has a lock on that file. Maybe he started the game twice? Or maybe he opened the save.dat with an editor in the same time?

Comment: I checked with him, and he assured me that he had no other instances of the game running.
It could be that I'm opening and closing it too soon. But if that's the case, why does it only occur on one device?

Comment: If its truly a transient error, you could retry the write.